# How to extend input component functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an input component in react that receives an `onChange` event from another component:

```
<input type="text" onChange={onChange} />
```

But I want to add a prop from another component to this component which makes the input only accept alphabets.

it would be something like this:

```
<input type="text" onKeyPress={ /* return true or false */ } />
```

But how can I use them both together?

```
const InputComponent = ({ onchange, value, alphabetOnly }) => {
  const handleKeyPress = e => {
    let alphabet =
      (e.charCode > 64 && e.charCode < 91) ||
      (e.charCode > 96 && e.charCode < 123);

    if (alphabet) {
      return true;
    }

    console.log("stop user from entering that char");

    return false;
  };

  return (
    <input
      onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
      onChange={onchange}
      value={value}
    />
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = e => setValue(e.target.value);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <InputComponent onchange={handleChange} value={value} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-cannon-6ueko

Comment: Your code in the sandbox seems to already be functioning properly

Comment: Why not using `onchange` to validate key input? just one handler can cover what you want to achieve.

Comment: you can also use [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefpattern) validation if that works for you `<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+ ..."`

Comment: @ROOT pattern doesn't stop user from inputting number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of onKeyPress add a validation condition inside onChange. Update the state value only only when the value is an alphabet and alphabetOnly prop is true. You can use `string.chatCodeAt` function to check if the value is an alphabet.

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/alphabet-only-js-fix-y7ey8?file=/src/App.js)

**Code Snippet**

```js
const InputComponent = ({ onchange, value, alphabetOnly }) => {
  const handleChange = e => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    if (alphabetOnly) {
      let alphabet =
        (val.charCodeAt(val.length - 1) > 64 &&
          val.charCodeAt(val.length - 1) < 91) ||
        (val.charCodeAt(val.length - 1) > 96 &&
          val.charCodeAt(val.length - 1) < 123) ||
        val === "";
      if (alphabet) {
        onchange(val);
      }
    } else {
      onchange(val);
    }
  };

  return <input onChange={handleChange} value={value} />;
};

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = val => setValue(val);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <InputComponent alphabetOnly onchange={handleChange} value={value} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`event.target.value.charCodeAt(0)` may solve your issue (it will read the first character from user input and return the keyCode relative to it).

keep in mind that users may still paste the input, so if the alphabet filter pass, make sure to add only the first character of the input string (`event.target.value[0]`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'onChange' function to validate inputs

```
onChange(event){
  .....
  validatInput(event.charCode)// your inpul validation logic function
  .....
}
```